# Correct way to add sprites from batch nodes inside CCMenu without increasing the number of draw calls

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Suppose I am using a CCSpriteFrameCache and adding frames like this

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"atlas.plist"];
mySpriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"atlas.png"];
CCSprite *oneSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"abc"]; //yes I do not use extensions, who need them?
[mySpriteSheet addChild:oneSprite];
```

This works wonderfully. You can add a lot of sprites to mySpriteSheet without increasing the draw calls, but suppose I want to use these sprites inside CCMenuItem, or in this case CCMenuItemSprite that is a subclass of CCMenuItem, like this:

```
CCSprite *spriteNormal = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imagemNormal];
CCSprite *spriteHighlight = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:imagemHighlight];

CCMenuItemSprite *myItem = [CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:spriteNormal
                                                      selectedSprite:spriteHighlight
                                                              target:target
                                            selector:@selector(doSomething)];
```

then the item goes inside a CCmenu

```
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:myItem, nil];
```

Now, here it is the question. If I do

```
[self addChild:menu];
```

the draw calls will be increased, even the sprites coming from the batch node and I cannot do

```
[mySpriteSheet addChild:menu];
```

because it will crash.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer (well not quite): you have to edit CCMenu's code for that to work. IMHO not worth the hassle, it's a lot easier to write your own button/menu class that supports batching.

Comment: I was suspecting this. I was thinking about creating my own class. I love Cocos but this is one more half cooked stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. Just like tilemaps. Reusable actions. ARC. Animations. Just from the top of my head. ;)